# Server Error for My Php Page

Tags: php, internal-server-error, server-error

I get Server Error when i try to open chart.php file.I use php 5.3.3 right now.However,this problem didn't occur in php5.4 .How can i fix this?

In php log file, there is an error related with chart.php.

[Mon Nov 12 05:04:19 2012] [error] [client 85.108.15.253] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/vhosts/phisto.org/httpdocs/chart.php on line 249, referer: http://www.phisto.org/browse.php

chart.php

```
    include("head.php");
    include("menu.php");
    include("functions.php");

    $deger = "";

    $resultsarray2 = $_SESSION["RESULTSARRAY2"];
    $rowcount = $_SESSION["ROWCOUNT"];
    $deger = $_POST['GRAPH'];




             // ROWCOUNT VE RESULTSARRAY2 GEREKLI !!!!!!!
            class obje {

                private $name;
                private $subset;
                private $degree;
                private $index ;
                public function obje($tempName,$tempDegree)
                {
                    $this->index = 0;
                    $this->subset = array();
                    $this->name = $tempName;
                    $this->degree = $tempDegree;
                }
                /* Nesnenin degree sini artýrýr. */
                public function degreeRaise()
                {
                    $this->degree += 1;
                }

                // getter function
                public function getName() {

                    return $this->name;
                }
                // getter function
                public function getDegree() {

                    return $this->degree;
                }
                // getter function
                public function getSubset() {

                    return $this->subset;
                }

                public function setSubset($sub)
                {           
                    $this->subset[] = $sub;
                    $this->index++;
                }
            }


            function indexOfObje($str,$array)
            {
                $count = 0;
                foreach( $array as $row) { 

                    if(strcmp($row->getName(),$str) == 0)
                        return $count;
                    $count++;
                }
                return -1;
            }

            $pathojens = array();
            $groups = array();
            $types = array();       
            $index;
            // arama sonucundaki satirlara gore islem yapilir.
            for($row = 0; $row < $rowcount; $row++) {

                $pathojen = $resultsarray2[$row][2];
                $group = $resultsarray2[$row][0];
                $type = $resultsarray2[$row][1];
                //echo $type."---".$group."***".$pathojen."????";

                if(($index = indexOfObje($pathojen,$pathojens)) > -1) {

                    $pathojens[$index]->degreeRaise(); /* Onceden sayýlan bir pathojen ise degree si artýtýlýr.
                                                        Bu durum type ve grubunda onceden sayýldýgýný gosterir,
                                                        ve onlarýnda degree si artýrýlýr.*/
                    $groups[indexOfObje($group,$groups)]->degreeRaise();
                    $types[indexOfObje($type,$types)]->degreeRaise();
                }
                else if(($index = indexOfObje($group,$groups)) > -1) {

                    $groups[$index]->degreeRaise(); /* Onceden sayýlan bir grup ise degree si artýtýlýr.
                                                    Bu durum type indaonceden sayýldýgýný gosterir,
                                                    ve onunda degree si artýrýlýr.*/
                    //echo $types[0]->getName();
                    //echo $type.indexOfObje($type,$types);
                    $types[indexOfObje($type,$types)]->degreeRaise();
                    /* Yeni bir pathojen objesi olusturulur.Grubunun alt 
                    kumesine konulur ve pathojen dizisine atýlýr.*/
                    $newObje = new obje($pathojen,1);
                    $pathojens[] = $newObje;

                    $groups[indexOfObje($group,$groups)]->setSubset($pathojen);

                }
                else if(($index = indexOfObje($type,$types)) > -1) {

                    $types[$index]->degreeRaise(); /* Onceden sayýlan bir type ise degree si artýtýlýr.*/

                    /* Yeni bir pathojen objesi olusturulur.Grubunun alt 
                    kumesine konulur ve pathojen dizisine atýlýr.*/
                    $newObje = new obje($pathojen,1);
                    $pathojens[] = $newObje;
                    /* Yeni bir pathojen objesi olusturulur.Grubunun alt 
                    kumesine konulur ve pathojen dizisine atýlýr.*/
                    $newObje2 = new obje($group,1);
                    $groups[] = $newObje2;  

                    $groups[indexOfObje($group,$groups)]->setSubset($pathojen);                     
                    $types[indexOfObje($type,$types)]->setSubset($group);


                }
                else { /* Yeni bir type,group ve pathojenin oldugu durum */

                    /* Yeni bir pathojen objesi olusturulur.Grubunun alt 
                    kumesine konulur ve pathojen dizisine atýlýr.*/
                    $newObje = new obje($pathojen,1);
                    $pathojens[] = $newObje;
                    /* Yeni bir group objesi olusturulur.Type nin alt 
                    kumesine konulur ve groups dizisine atýlýr.*/
                    $newObje2 = new obje($group,1);
                    $groups[] = $newObje2;  
                    /* Yeni bir type objesi olusturulur,type dizisine atýlýr.*/
                    $newObje3 = new obje($type,1);
                    $types[] = $newObje3;           

                    $groups[indexOfObje($group,$groups)]->setSubset($pathojen);                 
                    $types[indexOfObje($type,$types)]->setSubset($group);           

                }

            } 
            /* Datalar flashýn okuyabilmesi icin xmldosyaya yazilacak. */
            $document = new DOMDocument(); 
            $document->formatOutput = true; 
            $root = $document->createElement( "PieChart" ); 
            $document->appendChild( $root ); 
            echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

            /* Tür dizisinin boyutu xml e yazýlýr. */
            $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
            $size= $document->createElement( "sizeOfType" ); 
            $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( count($types) ) ); 
            $block->appendChild($size); 
            $root->appendChild( $block );

            /* Grup dizisinin boyutu xml e yazýlýr. */
            $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
            $size= $document->createElement( "sizeOfGroup" ); 
            $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( count($groups) ) ); 
            $block->appendChild($size); 
            $root->appendChild( $block );

            /* Strain dizisinin boyutu xml e yazýlýr. */
            $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
            $size= $document->createElement( "sizeOfPathojen" ); 
            $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( count($pathojens) ) ); 
            $block->appendChild($size); 
            $root->appendChild( $block );

            foreach($types as $type) {

                $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
                $size= $document->createElement( "typeName" ); 
                $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $type->getName() ) ); 
                $block->appendChild($size); 
                $root->appendChild( $block );

                $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
                $size= $document->createElement( "typeDegree" ); 
                $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $type->getDegree() ) ); 
                $block->appendChild($size); 
                $root->appendChild( $block );
            }

            /* her tür icin alt kume elemanlarý tek tek yazilir. */     
            $count = 0;
            foreach($types as $type) {

                /* her tür icin alt kume boyutu yazilir. */
                $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
                $size= $document->createElement( "sizeOfSubset" ); 
                $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( count($type->getSubset()) ) ); 
                $block->appendChild($size); 
                $root->appendChild( $block ); 

                for($count2 = 0; $count2 < count($type->getSubset()); $count2++) {

                    $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
                    $size= $document->createElement( "subsetOfType" ); 
                    $subset = $type->getSubset();
                    $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $subset[$count2] ) ); 
                    $block->appendChild($size); 
                    $root->appendChild( $block ); 
                }
                $count++;

            }

            foreach($groups as $group) {

                $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
                $size= $document->createElement( "groupName" ); 
                $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $group->getName() ) ); 
                $block->appendChild($size); 
                $root->appendChild( $block );

                $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
                $size= $document->createElement( "groupDegree" ); 
                $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $group->getDegree() ) ); 
                $block->appendChild($size); 
                $root->appendChild( $block );
            }

            /* her grup icin alt kume elemanlarý tek tek yazilir. */        
            $count = 0;
            foreach($groups as $group) {

                /* her grup icin alt kume boyutu yazilir. */
                $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
                $size= $document->createElement( "sizeOfSubset2" ); 
                $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( count($group->getSubset()) ) ); 
                $block->appendChild($size);             
                $root->appendChild( $block ); 

                for($count2 = 0; $count2 < count($group->getSubset()); $count2++) {

                    $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
                    $size= $document->createElement( "subsetOfType2" ); 
                    $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $group->getSubset()[$count2] ) ); 
                    $block->appendChild($size);         
                    $root->appendChild( $block ); 

                    $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
                    $size= $document->createElement( "degree" ); 

                    // pathojenin pathojenler arrayindeki indexi bulunur.
                    $in = indexOfObje($group->getSubset()[$count2],$pathojens); 
                    // pathojenin degree si yazilir.
                    $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $pathojens[ $in ]->getDegree()) ); 
                    $block->appendChild($size);         
                    $root->appendChild( $block ); 
                }       
            }


            $document->saveXML(); 
            $document->save("chart.xml"); 




            /* Flashi ekrana bas */
            if($deger == "Pie Chart")
            {
                echo '
                <EMBED ID="Shockwave" SRC="pie_chart.swf" HEIGHT=400 WIDTH=950 PALETTE=BACKGROUND Quality=AutoLow Loop=FALSE Play=TRUE
                Scale=ShowAll SAlign=L ALT="" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer/"></OBJECT></center>';
            }
            else if($deger == "Bar Chart")
            {
                echo'   <EMBED ID="Shockwave2" SRC="bar_chart.swf" HEIGHT=600 WIDTH=950 PALETTE=BACKGROUND Quality=AutoLow Loop=FALSE Play=TRUE
                Scale=ShowAll SAlign=L ALT="" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer/"></OBJECT></center>';
            }


            include("foot.php");
    ?>

        $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
        $size= $document->createElement( "typeDegree" ); 
        $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $type->getDegree() ) ); 
        $block->appendChild($size); 
        $root->appendChild( $block );
    }

    /* her tür icin alt kume elemanlarý tek tek yazilir. */     
    $count = 0;
    foreach($types as $type) {

        /* her tür icin alt kume boyutu yazilir. */
        $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
        $size= $document->createElement( "sizeOfSubset" ); 
        $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( count($type->getSubset()) ) ); 
        $block->appendChild($size); 
        $root->appendChild( $block ); 

        for($count2 = 0; $count2 < count($type->getSubset()); $count2++) {

            $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
            $size= $document->createElement( "subsetOfType" ); 
            $subset = $type->getSubset();
            $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $subset[$count2] ) ); 
            $block->appendChild($size); 
            $root->appendChild( $block ); 
        }
        $count++;

    }

    foreach($groups as $group) {

        $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
        $size= $document->createElement( "groupName" ); 
        $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $group->getName() ) ); 
        $block->appendChild($size); 
        $root->appendChild( $block );

        $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
        $size= $document->createElement( "groupDegree" ); 
        $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $group->getDegree() ) ); 
        $block->appendChild($size); 
        $root->appendChild( $block );
    }

    /* her grup icin alt kume elemanlarý tek tek yazilir. */        
    $count = 0;
    foreach($groups as $group) {

        /* her grup icin alt kume boyutu yazilir. */
        $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
        $size= $document->createElement( "sizeOfSubset2" ); 
        $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( count($group->getSubset()) ) ); 
        $block->appendChild($size);             
        $root->appendChild( $block ); 

        for($count2 = 0; $count2 < count($group->getSubset()); $count2++) {

            $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
            $size= $document->createElement( "subsetOfType2" ); 
            /* LINE 249 */
            $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $group->getSubset()[$count2] ) ); 
            $block->appendChild($size);         
            $root->appendChild( $block ); 

            $block = $document->createElement( "datas" ); 
            $size= $document->createElement( "degree" ); 

            // pathojenin pathojenler arrayindeki indexi bulunur.
            $in = indexOfObje($group->getSubset()[$count2],$pathojens); 
            // pathojenin degree si yazilir.
            $size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $pathojens[ $in ]->getDegree()) ); 
            $block->appendChild($size);         
            $root->appendChild( $block ); 
        }       
    }


    $document->saveXML(); 
    $document->save("chart.xml"); 




    /* Flashi ekrana bas */
    if($deger == "Pie Chart")
    {
        echo '
        <EMBED ID="Shockwave" SRC="pie_chart.swf" HEIGHT=400 WIDTH=950 PALETTE=BACKGROUND Quality=AutoLow Loop=FALSE Play=TRUE
        Scale=ShowAll SAlign=L ALT="" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer/"></OBJECT></center>';
    }
    else if($deger == "Bar Chart")
    {
        echo'   <EMBED ID="Shockwave2" SRC="bar_chart.swf" HEIGHT=600 WIDTH=950 PALETTE=BACKGROUND Quality=AutoLow Loop=FALSE Play=TRUE
        Scale=ShowAll SAlign=L ALT="" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer/"></OBJECT></center>';
    }


    include("foot.php");
 ?>
```

Screenshot is below.

Thanks.

[image: Server Error]

Comment: Can we see the code of /var/www/vhosts/phisto.org/httpdocs/chart.php, especially around the line 249?..

Comment: Which php version are you using ? i think line 249 is `$in = indexOfObje($group->getSubset()[$count2],$pathojens); ` and this `$group->getSubset()[$count2]` only support in PHP 5.4

Comment: LINE 249 :

$size->appendChild( $document->createTextNode( $group->getSubset()[$count2] ) );

## I use php 5.3.3

Comment: this `$group->getSubset()[$count2]` not supported in PHP 5.3.3

Comment: $subset = group->getSubset();
$var = $subset[$count2];

Is this unsupported ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I used this and the problem is solved.

$subset = group->getSubset(); $var = $subset[$count2];

Answer (score 1):

You have downgraded from PHP 5.4 to 5.3?

It is advisable to check **[the migration guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)** where you can take a look at point #3:

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. **foo()[0]**.

This functionality didn't appear in PHP 5.3, so it's complaining about your line 249:

```
$in = indexOfObje($group->getSubset()[$count2],$pathojens);
```

Try this instead (note: I didn't test!):

```
$subset = $group->getSubset();
$in = indexOfObje($subset[$count2],$pathojens);
```

See this link for more info: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Answer (score 0):

Your error suggests that you have a syntax error, eg. your code is not valid which means you should fix your code according to the error (unexpected '[') on line 249. However, `$class->method()[$count]` is not supported in PHP 5.3.3, which you are using. I suggest you either upgrade your PHP version or change your code a bit. Also, the screenshot suggests that you have errors disabled in your PHP.ini, you should enable them (E_ALL) for development servers.